# Hyper-V - No Hypervisor on DELL PowerEdge R710

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, dell, dell-poweredge

We can not get our Hyper-V core server up and running with a DELL PowerEdge R710. We tried it with Windows Server 2012 R2 and Windows Server 2016 but we always get the message "*no hypervisor is running*" right after starting a VM.

We can install and configure Hyper-V including adding VMs to it but those won't start. We activated the BIOS setting for Virtualization Technology and Execute Disable (please see screenshots) but with no luck. When I run systeminfo.exe I see that all four Hyper-V settings labeled with YES

Any idea what's missing?

Would very much appreciate help on this as I have read that the R710 is good server for virtualization.

Following the BIOS settings:

### BIOS Settings screenshot #1

[image: BIOS Settings screenshot #1]

### BIOS Settings screenshot #2

[image: BIOS Settings screenshot #2]

Comment: Did you install the Hyper-V role before or after enabling virtualization in the BIOS? If before, then remove the Hyper-V role, reboot and reinstall it.

If you enabled virtualization in BIOS, installed Hyper-V and rebooted, I would confirm the HV Host and Hyper-V Virtual Machine Management Services are started.

Comment: I did install Hyper-V Core so there I don't have to enable the Hyper-V role. I could install Hyper-V Core on two Dell PowerEdge R610 without any troube (same BIOS settings etc.).

Comment: What's in your event logs?

Comment: "no hypervisor is running" check you BIOS settings. Settings are ok, I even removed the power cable for a minute. I will try an BIOS upgrade, maybe that will do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Latest BIOS update was required.